# Log4j's ThreadContext clears the automatically

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, log4j

I am inserting a key into `ThreadContext` map at the start of the application like so,

```
protected void doFilterWrapped(ContentCachingRequestWrapper request,
      ContentCachingResponseWrapper response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    // some code...
    ThreadContext.put(Constants.REQUEST_ID, requestID);
    ThreadContext.put(requestID + Constants.HASH + "retryCount", "-1");
    // some more code...
  }
```

Now in someother class I am trying to update the value of key `requestID + Constants.HASH + "retryCount"` like so,

```
String key = ThreadContext.get(Constants.REQUEST_ID) + Constants.HASH + "retryCount";
      if (ThreadContext.containsKey(key)) {
        ThreadContext.put(key, String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(ThreadContext.get(key)) + 1));
      } else {
        ThreadContext.put(key, "-1");
      }
      System.out.println("\n\n  " + ThreadContext.get(key) + " \n\n");
```

But it only works once and after that it is not able to find the `key`, i.e `ThreadContext.containsKey(key)` is `false`.

Can someone explain me what the problem is.

Comment: it's possible that something else called ThreadContext.init() which would clear context map which was holding your value. Try to set breakpoint there and you will see

Comment: Checked, no such call has been made. The thread for both the above calls are different, may be that is causing issue?

Comment: Thread shouldn't matter because contextMap is static field. It would be easier to just check what is inside context map when contains() returns false. Also i don't know if it's a problem here but this part ```"ThreadContext.get(Constants.REQUEST_ID) + Constants.HASH + "retryCount";"``` shouldnt have bracket in this place:
```"ThreadContext.get(Constants.REQUEST_ID + Constants.HASH + "retryCount");" ```?

Comment: I have checked this as well, the new Threads are rabbitMQ threads provided by spring. All the values are gone except the key = requestId. I don't know why is it behaving so abnormally.

Comment: A `ThreadContext` is valid only for the current thread. Can you explain how do you pass it between threads?

Comment: That is my question, i want to know the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the thead context inheritable system property?  In your app startup, add this line:

```
System.setProperty("isThreadContextMapInheritable", "true");
```

With this property enabled, child threads will inherit the thread context.